# Why $\{0,1\}$ is subobject classifier in $Sets$

Tags: category-theory

I don't want to use the fact that pullbacks in $Sets$ are just subset of $X \times Y$

[image: subobject classifier in $Sets$]

Here $p_1$ and $q_1$ are unique (because $1$ is terminal object), $f(1) = 1$. We want to have unique $g$ by specifying injection $p_2$.

$f \circ p_1 = g \circ p_2 \Leftrightarrow g(p_2(x))=1 \Leftrightarrow g|_P (x) = 1$

Also we need unique $u$ for given $q_2$

$p_2 \circ u = q_2 \Leftrightarrow u = q_2|_Y$

So the only condition for $g$ is $g|_P (x) = 1$. Why we also have $g|_{Y \backslash P} (x) = 0$?

Comment: You write that you don't want to use the fact that pullbacks in **Set** are subsets - nevertheless, do you understand why this is true? Because this is basically what our answers are saying . . .

Comment: Ye, i've proofed it using the universal property of $X \times Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $u$ to exist for *all* $Q$ and $q_2$ which make the outer diagram commute.  If you have a point $x\in Y\setminus P$ such that $g(x)=1$, then you can let $Q=\{x\}$ and $q_2$ be the inclusion, and then no $u$ will exist making the diagram commute.

Comment: Drat, beat me to it!

Comment: Let's say. $P={a,b}, Y={a,b,c},Q={c}$. $u(c) = a, g = 1$. Then it commutes, isn't it?

Comment: No, because $p_2(u(c))=a$ but $q_2(c)=c$.

Comment: Ye, but this is nothing we can do with $g$ in this case. I mean the problem is not about $g|_{Y\backslash P}(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Ximik it **is** due to $g$ - or rather, the fact that $g$ does not satisfy the desired property is what leads to the existence of a $Q, q_2$ which cannot be "filled in".

Comment: @NoahSchweber but if i set $g(a)=g(b)=1, g(c)=0$ i still have the problem, specified by Eric Wofsey.

Comment: @Ximik No you don't - now the outer square doesn't commute! $g(q_2(c))=0$ but $f(q_1(c))=1$. We need such a $u$ to exist *whenever the outer square commutes*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the definition of a subobject classifier doesn't just require that a certain square *commute*, but rather that it be a *pullback*.  It is indeed true that as long as $g(P)=\{1\}$, the square $p_1, p_2, f, g$ will commute.

However, suppose $g(x)=1$ for some $x\not\in P$. Then let $Q=\{x\}$, $q_2$ the obvious embedding of $Q$ as a subset of $Y$, and $q_1$ the only possible map. Now there are **no** $u$ which make the larger diagram commute: where can such a $u$ send $x$?